# Python : How to use Multinomial Logistic Regression using SKlearn

Tags: python, data-mining, logistic-regression, scikit-learn

I have a test dataset and train dataset as below. I have provided sample data with min records, but my data has more than 1000's of record. Here if you see `E` is my target variable which I need to predict using an algorithm. It has only four categories like 1, 2, 3, 4. It can take only any of these values.

#### Training Dataset:

```
A    B    C    D    E
1    20   30   1    1
2    22   12   33   2
3    45   65   77   3
12   43   55   65   4
11   25   30   1    1
22   23   19   31   2
31   41   11   70   3
1    48   23   60   4
```

#### Test Dataset:

```
A    B    C    D    E
11   21   12   11
1    2    3    4
5    6    7    8 
99   87   65   34 
11   21   24   12
```

Since `E` has only 4 categories, I thought of predicting this using Multinomial Logistic Regression (1 vs Rest Logic). I am trying to implement it using Python.

I know the logic that we need to set these targets in a variable and use an algorithm to predict any of these values:

```
output = [1,2,3,4]
```

But I am stuck at a point on how to use it using python (sklearn) to loop through these values and what algorithm should I use to predict the output values? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Put the training data into two numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

# data from columns A - D
Xtrain = np.array([[1,    20,   30,   1],
                   [2,    22,   12,   33],
                   [3,    45,   65,   77],
                   [12,   43,   55,   65],
                   [11,   25,   30,   1],
                   [22,   23,   19,   31],
                   [31,   41,   11,   70],
                   [1,    48,   23,   60]])

# data from column E
ytrain = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Then train a logistic regression model:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

lr = LogisticRegression().fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
```

Make predictions (on the training data):

```
yhat = lr.predict(Xtrain)
```

=> results in "1, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4".. so it's got 7 right and 1 wrong.

Calculate accuracy:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

accuracy_score(ytrain, yhat)
```

=> results in 87.5% accuracy

To make predictions for new data, just create another numpy array containing your test data and call `lr.predict` on it.

You might also want to look into parameter tuning to improve your score. For example the LogisticRegression class has some parameters that control regularization - tuning them with methods found in sklearn.grid_search might improve your score.

Comment: From what I know about sklearn, this is not accurate for the multinomial case unless `multi_class='multinomial'` is used for `LogisticRegression()` with the supported solvers

Comment: @HammanSamuel I just tried to run that code again with sklearn 0.22.1 and it still works (looks like almost 4 years have passed). It doesn't matter what you set multi_class to, both "multinomial" and "ovr" work (default is "auto"). As far as I understand with "multinomial" it trains 1 model with 3 outputs at once, while with "ovr" ("One Versus Rest") it trains n models (one for each class). But both methods work with multiple classes.